# How do I write the formula in Excel for a nested if when value is false on multiple ifs?

Tags: excel

I have a nested if that has

=IF(A1=10,"you have 10 points","otherwise blank",IF(A1=20,"you have 20 points","otherwise blank",IF(A1=30,"you have 30 points","otherwise blank")))

What I want is that if it finds 10,20 or 30 to give those outputs otherwise don't display any output, but I get an error that say

> You've entered too many arguments for this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
=If(OR(A1=10,A1=20,A1=30),"You have " & A1 & " points","")
```

Or:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,{10,20,30},0)),"You have " & A1 & " points","")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this:

```
=if(A1=10,"you have 10 points",if(A1=20,"you have 20 points",if(A1=30,"you have 30 points","")))
```

The logic is as following:

1. If A1=10, you have 10 points
2. If not, then if A1=20, you have 20 points
3. If not, then if A1=30, you have 30 points
4. If not, then it means A1 does not equal either 10, 20 or 30, so return blank.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula should be something like this:

=IF(OR(A1=10,A1=20, A1=30), A1, "")

Comment: Doesn't quite do what OP wants.